# Gnu sed can e execute a bash function increasing value

Tags: bash, sed

How gnu sed can e execute a bash function increasing a counter value as

```
$ k(){ ((i++)); echo $i ;} ;export -f k
$ i=; echo -e 'oAo\nooAo\nAo' | sed -E '/A/e k'
1
oAo
1
ooAo
1
Ao
```

Fail instead of doing a counter correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process can't affect the environment of its parent process.  When you use sed's  `e` command, it forks a new shell to run the command (which inherits the exported `k` function), and any changes made to that shell's `i` variable are lost when it terminates (which is as soon as the k function exits).

If you want to increment a variable, you'll have to store it somewhere outside of the environment.  e.g. in a file.  If you don't want to use a file, there's no reason why you can't use something like `memcached` or `redis` or an SQL database.

For example:

```
k() {
  local counterfile i
  counterfile='/tmp/counter.i'
  [ -e "$counterfile" ] && i=$(cat "$counterfile")
  ((i++))
  echo "$i" | tee "$counterfile"
}
export -f k
```

When you run it now, the counter increments:

```
$ rm /tmp/counter.i
$ printf 'oAo\nooAo\nAo' | sed -E '/A/e k'
1
oAo
2
ooAo
3
Ao
$ echo 100 > /tmp/counter.i
$ printf 'oAo\nooAo\nAo' | sed -E '/A/e k'
101
oAo
102
ooAo
103
Ao
```

---

BTW, while sed's `e` command is useful, I think perl would be a better language for what you're doing.  e.g.

```
$ printf 'oAo\nooAo\nAo' |
    perl -lpe 'BEGIN { $i=shift || 0 };
               if (/A/) {print ++$i}' 10
11
oAo
12
ooAo
13
Ao
```

If you don't provide an argument, `$i` defaults to zero.

If you want the script to look more "sed-like", there are many ways to increment and print the `$i` counter variable on a line containing `A`.  Here's another one:

```
/A/ && print ++$i
```

If there may be multiple matches per line and you need to increment and print the counter on every match, then you need to iterate over the matches. e.g.

```
$ printf 'oAo\noAoAoAo\nAo' |
    perl -lpe 'BEGIN { $i=shift || 0 };
               for (/oA/g) {print ++$i}'
1
oAo
2
3
4
oAoAoAo
Ao
```

Or if you don't need a cumulative total, but just need to count the matches on each line:

```
$ printf 'oAo\noAoAoAo\nAo' |
    perl -lne '$c = () = $_ =~ /oA/g;
               printf "%02i:%s\n", $c, $_'
01:oAo
03:oAoAoAo
00:Ao
```

This last one probably needs a bit of explanation.  Reading it **backwards**, the `$c = () = $_ =~ /oA/g` statement first does a regex match on `/oA/g` and returns the result in list context to an empty list `()`, which is then assigned to variable `$c`. Because `$c` is a scalar variable, not an array/list, this is evaluated in scalar context so returns the number of elements in that list.   This is a fairly common perl idiom for counting the number of matches.

---

Note: perl's `-p` option makes it run a lot like sed (i.e. iterate over its input and print each line after it has been processed unless a statement prevents it being printed).  And perl's `-n` option makes it run a lot like `sed -n` (iterate over input, printing only what it is explicitly instructed to print).

Finally, it's worth noting that the sed and bash function version of this forks `bash`, `cat`, and `tee` for every input line that matches `/A/`.  The perl version forks nothing, it just iterates over its input.   Also worth noting is that many of the things you'd have to fork an external program to do in bash can be done internally by perl using its own built-in syntax (or one of the many thousands of library modules)

Comment: Real case multi occurences per line so
echo -e 'oAo\noAoAoAo\nAo' |
 perl -l -p -e 'BEGIN { $i=shift || 0 } ; /A/G&&print ++$i

cannot work, help out by editing the answer please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with that comment.   Are you saying you need to increment and print the counter every time there's a match on a line and that there may be multiple matches per line?  if so, then you need to iterate over the matches.  e.g.  `printf 'oAo\noAoAoAo\nAo' | perl -l -p -e 'BEGIN { $i=shift || 0 } ; for (/oA/g) {print ++$i}'`.   BTW, I changed `echo` to `printf` because `echo` is unreliable and has unpredictable behaviour depending on which version of echo you're using and which shell you're using.  printf not only behaves consistently, it is better.

Comment: EXCELLENT.


THANKS BILLION

Comment: Billion and one, billion and two, ...

Answer (score 0):

As you're on GNU sed, you can get the desired results without recourse to a
user defined function. Here we utilize the hold space to hold the incrementing count.

```
echo -e 'oAo\nooAoAoA\no' | 
sed -En "/A/!d
  p;:a
  H;g
  s/^(\n*).*/expr '\1' : '.*'/ep
  g;s//\1/;x;s/^\n*//;s/A//;//ba
"
```

Output:

```
oAo
1
ooAoAoA
2
3
4
```

Comment: coding into SO is spurned.